# Map values from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe with the correspondence between two values:

[image]

A another list with only one of the variables:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to make the mapping like:

```
df[l[0]]
```

and get 1

```
df[l[1]]
```

and get 2

As if it was a dictionary, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df.loc[df['key']==l[0], 'value']
```

returns

```
0    1
1    1
```

Another way would be to set_index of the df to key.

```
df.set_index('key', inplace = True)
df.loc[l[0]].values[0]
```

Comment: Yes, like df.loc[df['key']==l[0], 'value'].values[0] I thoght it could be a cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

Another way is map by `Series` or by `dict` but is necessary unique value of `key`s, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':list('aabcc'),
                   'value':[1,1,2,3,3]})

s = df.drop_duplicates('key').set_index('key')['value']
print (s)
key
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: value, dtype: int64

d = df.drop_duplicates('key').set_index('key')['value'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}

l = ['a','b','c'] 

print (s[l[0]])
1

print (d[l[1]])
2
```